# What is the red light in the hotel bath for?

Tags: hotels

I've recently stayed in a hotel with a red light bulb in the top of the bathroom.

The red light bulb works only for a limited time until it automatically shuts down.

Anyone knows what is this red light for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

High wattage [heat lamp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PSJNFK)

It's not something to leave on indefinitely, only while a user cares to be warmed up

Answer (score 2):

If you wake up to use the restroom during the night, you use the red light which allows you to stay drowsy and not wake you up like normal lights.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the type and wattage of the light used. The majority of the ones I’ve seen mounted in the ceiling were of the high wattage heat lamp style. The majority of those looked like red flood lamps. The lights used as night lights are generally under-mounted, low wattage lights. The majority of these are not necessarily red. But recently, more of them are designed to have light on the blue end of the spectrum eliminated. Light on the red end of the spectrum provides for more surface heating. Light on the blue end provides for more deeply penetrating energy.